# Bash for loop with string var containing spaces

Tags: bash, variable, escape-characters, for, whitespace

In my directory I have two files with space, `foo bar` and `another file`. I also have two files without space, `file1` and `file2`.

The following script works:

```
for f in foo\ bar another\ file; do file "$f"; done
```

This script also works:

```
for f in 'foo bar' 'another file'; do file "$f"; done
```

But the following script doesn't work:

```
files="foo\ bar another\ file"
for f in $files; do file "$f"; done
```

Not even this script works:

```
files="'foo bar' 'another file'"
for f in $files; do file "$f"; done
```

But, if the files do not contain space, the script works:

```
files="file1 file2"
for f in $files; do file "$f"; done
```

Thanks!

### Edit

Code snippet of my script:

```
while getopts "i:a:c:d:f:g:h" arg; do
  case $arg in
    i) files=$OPTARG;;
    # ...
  esac
done

for f in $files; do file "$f"; done
```

With files without spaces, my script works. But I would like to run the script passing files with spaces as argument in one of these ways:

```
./script.sh -i "foo\ bar another\ file"
./script.sh -i foo\ bar another\ file
./script.sh -i "'foo bar' 'another file'"
./script.sh -i 'foo bar' 'another file'
```

Comment: You may want to try using an array. This should explain how to use a bash array with elements that have spaces in them and how to iterate over the array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084257/bash-array-with-spaces-in-elements

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify how `files` will be populated. Will it be all arguments? Some? A command line option? Also, this is almost certainly a dupe of [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766). Does it answer your question?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Your last code snipped: It makes no sense to use `getopts` in this script if you only have a single option that signals "use these files". The script could just loop over `"$@"` to process the files.

Comment: I have several args

Comment: @PedroSiqueira Is the `-i` option the only one that takes what amounts to multiple values?

Comment: You could have multiple  `-i "foo bar" -i "another file"` and use an array to store each values (see @roiama's answer for that part)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your command line parsing, arrange with the pathname operands to always be the last ones on the command line:

```bash
./myscript -a -b -c -- 'foo bar' 'another file' file[12]
```

The parsing of the options would look something like

```bash
a_opt=false b_opt=false c_opt=false
while getopts abc opt; do
     case $opt in
         a) a_opt=true ;;
         b) b_opt=true ;;
         c) c_opt=true ;;
         *) echo error >&2; exit 1
    esac
done

shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

for pathname do
    # process pathname operand "$pathname" here
done
```

The `shift` will make sure to shift off the handled options so that the pathname operands are the only things left in the list of positional parameters.

If that's not possible, allow the `-i` option to be specified multiple times and collect the given arguments in an array each time you come across it in the loop:

```bash
pathnames=() a_opt=false b_opt=false c_opt=false
while getopts abci: opt; do
     case $opt in
         a) a_opt=true ;;
         b) b_opt=true ;;
         c) c_opt=true ;;
         i) pathnames+=( "$OPTARG" ) ;;
         *) echo error >&2; exit 1
    esac
done

shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

for pathname in "${pathnames[@]}"; do
    # process pathname argument "$pathname" here
done
```

This would be called as

```bash
./myscript -a -b -c -i 'foo bar' -i 'another file' -i file1 -i file2
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! But what if I want to pass a wildcard like `./script -a -b -c -i "*.mp4"`, and process all files ending ".mp4"?

Comment: @PedroSiqueira I would avoid this if possible. You would have to find a safe way to expand that globbing pattern to a list of pathnames, and allow for it to also _not_ be a pattern (or, if you have a separate option for that). One could possibly plug it into `find`, but that would be fiddly. You could definitely ask a separate question about that, because it's most definitely non-trivial to do safely.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using `bash` you can use an array for this

```
#!/bin/bash
files=('foo bar' 'another file' file1 'file2')
for f in "${files[@]}"; do file -- "$f"; done
```

Quoting is required for file names containing whitespace or any other character that is special in the syntax of the shell such as `;`, `|`, `&`, `*` and many more.

Double-quoting is also required around expansions in list contexts at least (like `"${files[@]}"` and `"$f"` here) for file names containing globbing characters (`*`, `?`, `[`, and `\` in some versions of `bash`, and more if `extglob` is enabled) or characters of `$IFS` (space, tab and newline by default).

It's optional (but I'd recommend it) for file names that contain none of those and no non-ASCII character.

If the list of files comes from the current working directory you can use wildcards as you'd expect, e.g. `files=(*f*)` to match any file or directory with `f` in its name, though you'd want `shopt -s nullglob` beforehand to avoid getting a literal `*f*` if there's no match. (But then you could probably just use `for f in *f*; do...done` and avoid the array entirely).

The `--` marker for `file` tells it that any subsequent parameter is a filename - even if it starts with a dash.

Read more with `man bash` (search for `Arrays`) or just `info bash arrays`.

Answer (score 6):

There's a bit of a difference between the four script invocations you posted.

```
./script.sh -i "'foo bar' 'another file'"
./script.sh -i "foo\ bar another\ file"
```

The above two both pass to the script `-i` as the first argument, and a single string as the second. In the first one, that's `'foo bar' 'another file'`, and in the second, it's `foo\ bar another\ file`. In the shell language, both are valid ways to present the two strings (or filenames) `foo bar` and `another file`. But the quote and backslash processing only applies when the strings are on a raw command line, not when they're inside a variable, as they end up in the string.

```
./script.sh -i foo\ bar another\ file
./script.sh -i 'foo bar' 'another file'
```

On the other hand, these two pass a total of *three* arguments: `-i`, `foo bar`, and `another file`.

The difference is somewhat important in that it's much easier to deal safely with distinct arguments. You just need to keep them intact, and don't have to process the quotes and escapes embedded within.

Also, importantly, running something like `script ./*.txt` will pass the filenames as distinct arguments.

E.g. this would just call `file` on both files if called as `script 'foo bar' another\ file`:

```
#! /bin/sh -
for f in "$@"; do
    file -- "$f"
done
```

Or, even simpler and more portable as `for` loops over the positional parameters by default:

```
#! /bin/sh -
for f do
    file -- "$f"
done
```

---

But you have the getopts there, too. And with the filenames as distinct arguments, only the first would appear as the argument to `-i`. Here, there's basically two common options.

Either have the user use the `-i` option repeatedly, collecting the filenames to an array, so:

```
#! /bin/bash -
files=()
while getopts "i:" arg; do
  case $arg in
    (i) files+=("$OPTARG");;
  esac
done

for f in "${files[@]}"; do file -- "$f"; done
```

and run as `script -i "foo bar" -i "another file"`. (Running `script -i file1 file2` would have `file2` ignored.) Similarly you could add another array to collect filenames given through another option.

Or, have the option set the "mode" the script works in, and take the filenames as a list distinct from the options. `getopts` leaves all the arguments intact, you'll just have to drop the ones it processed with `shift`. So:

```
#! /bin/bash -

unset -v mode
while getopts "ie" arg; do
  case $arg in
    (i) mode=i;;
    (e) mode=e;;
    (*) : handle usage error;;
  esac
done
shift "$((OPTIND - 1))"

case "$mode" in
  (i) for f do file -- "$f"; done;;
  (e) echo "do something else with the files";;
  (*) echo "error: mode not specified" >&2;;
esac
```

and then run it as `script -i "foo bar" "another file"` or `script -i -- -file-starting-with-dash- -other-file-` or `script -i -- *`.

I'm assuming here that you are also doing something else with `getopts` other than taking the `-i` in, since otherwise you could just drop the flag entirely. :) But what other options you have, somewhat affects what the most sensibly (or customary) solution is.

Also if your loop only calls `file` on the files, you could just run `file -- "${files[@]}"` or `file -- "$@"` and skip the loop.

---

However, if you want to be able to this:

```
script -i foo bar -e doo daa
```

and have the script do one thing for the files `foo` and `bar`, and another thing for `doo` and `daa`, then that's a bit of a different issue. It can be done, sure, but `getopts` might not be the tool for that.

See also:

- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays for arrays in particular
- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable/444949#444949) which also discusses arrays, even though the title is about commands.

And of course:

- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

for the issues with trying to deal with multiple distinct arbitrary strings (filenames) within a single variable.

Answer (score -2):

Bash is not too good at dealing with variables with space in them. You have to use the "rename" functionality to help you with this a bit like below:

Use below if you are on a debian like system

```
sudo apt-get install rename
```

Use below if you are on a red hat like system

```
sudo yum install install rename
```

Move into the directory where your files are

```
cd your_target_directory
```

Rename all the files/variables containing the space character. With this step no more problems with the space

```
rename 's/ /_/g' *
```

Proceed without issue from here... enjoy

Comment: Note that spaces is just one of several problematic characters that are _valid_ in filenames.  Others includes tabs, newlines, characters that are part of globbing patterns (such as `*` and `?` etc.), control characters, emojis and other non-latin characters (visible and invisible).  It's _easier_ to write code that  correctly handles all valid filenames, than to rename files that broken code can't handle.